# Get only one character case insensitive in a globally case sensitive RegExp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, xregexp

I'd like to find pairs of strings with Javasacript RegExp in a way that:
1. If the two characters are the same letter
2. If the two characters are of different case

So 'aA' is OK, but 'AA' is not.

The string is continuous, so there are no spaces, newlines, commas, etc. in it - only letters **[a-zA-Z]**.

I came up with the following regular expression for that:
**/(.)((?!\1)(?i\1))/g**

Roughly explained: take a character, if the following character is the same (case sensitively) then discard first character (and go on), if the following character is NOT the same, but case insensitively it is, then I found a pair.

The regex is working in different online testers (it works with a very long string), but I cannot get it to work with Javascript code.

So this throws an error with JS code:

```
// Javascript code - throws error
var base = "aaAAAaBbBBBaa";

// regex syntax: /(.)((?!\1)(?i\1))/g
var regEx = new RegExp( "(.)((?!\\1)(?i)\\1)", "g" );

console.log( regEx.test( base ) );
//the correct matches should be (in order): "aA", Aa", "Bb"
```

I tried using XRegExp, but nothing worked:

```
// XRegExp code - throws error
var searchPattern = XRegExp( '(?<char>.)((?!\\k<char>)((?i)\\k<char>))', 'g' );

console.log( searchPattern.test( "aaaAbbBaAAA" ) );
// the correct matches should be (in order): "aA", "bB", "aA"
```

I'm pretty out of ideas now - the regex works (tested it), but not in JS. :(

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Is there a mistake in my JS / XRegExp code?

P.S.: this is for [Advent Of Code](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/5) 5th Dec. 2018 :)

Comment: Yes, it's definitely the same problem. JS regex (even the XRegExp) still cannot do this. Thank you!

Comment: If it's just a single character, you could work around it by replacing all caps `([A-Z])` with `,$1,` than run the new string with `,([a-z]),\1|([a-z]),\2,` If group 1 matches it's capital first, if group 2 matches it's capital second. But, I don't know if this could be extended to substrings when more than a single character is sought.